# What is the minimum sample-size required to be confident that half of American adults have eaten ice-cream at least once in their life?

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size

Suppose that you conduct a survey in which you ask American adults if they have eaten ice-cream at least once in the past.

What is the minimum sample size required for you to be at least 90% confident that at least 50% of American adults have eaten ice-cream at least once in the past?

If you find it useful, then you are allowed to assume the following:

- Assume that American adults are selected with uniformly random probability. For example, the survey respondents are unlikely to all be students from the same University.
- "50% of Americans" and "90% confident" are perfectly precise. They are not known to only one or two significant figures, which might otherwise be assumed. If your answer is numeric in nature, then it must be precise to at least 3 significant figures.
- You may assume that survey respondents always answer honestly. I realize that this is an unrealistic assumption, but it might make the mathematics more tractable.
- You may assume that survey respondents always answer the survey question. Survey respondents will not hang-up the phone if you call them, or refuse to take the survey. American adults who refuse to take part in the survey may be more likely, or less likely, to have eaten ice-cream than those persons who choose to respond to the survey. Hence, assume that no-one will decline to respond to the survey.
- Not only are survey respondents honest, but that they will remember every ice-cream-eating incident they have participated in the past. For example, they may For example, a lactose-intolerant person will **not** forget that one day (Specifically, July 16 1997) they had some pistachio flavored ice-cream purchased on in the city of Des Moines, in spite of their allergy, when they were feeling particularly self-indulgent.
- You may assume anyone who was an American as of 8:00PM  May 15, 2020 Greenwich mean time (GMT) has not died. Clearly, some Americans have died since then, such as George Perry Floyd Jr. However, we must make the problem mathematically tractable.

It may not be clear what an "American adult" is.

- We define the word "adult" to refer to any person who was at least 18 years old on May 15, 2020 at 8:00PM Greenwich mean time (GMT).
- Imagine a cone-like object whose point is centered at the center of planet earth. The cone-like object intersects planet Earth's surface at the legal borders of the United States. The "cone" radiates into outer-space infinetly. An "American" is defined to be anyone who was inside of this cone-like object at least 90% of the time in the 365 days proceeding May 15, 2020 8:00PM Greenwich mean time (GMT). The time range is inclusive. That is May 15, 2020 8:00PM is included. If times are represented as real number, then need not be strictly less than May 15, 2020 8:00PM.

  - "Americans " may include non-citizens (undocumented workers) if they resided within the American cone the requisite 90% of the time.
  - Any American citizen who went went on vacation in Europe for more than 3 months during the specified year is considered to not be an "American" for purposes of the ice-cream study. Such a person was physically located inside of the American cone less than 75% of the time, which abridges the 90% required in the definition.

In case you are having trouble distinguishing the forest from the trees, I will repeat the question here:

> What is the minimum sample size required for you to be at least 90% confident that at least 50% of American adults have eaten ice-cream at least once in the past?

Comment: I'm not sure if the question is answerable, as it depends on the answers you get, which depend on the true ratio of how many adults have ever eaten ice-cream. I.e. if everyone you interview answers "no" (which is unlikely, but definitely possible within the listed conditions), then no sample size can be sufficient.

Comment: ... but for a proper random sample size of five, *if* all five answer yes, then that gives a 90% confidence that at least 54.9% have eaten icecream, using Clopper-Pearson method for Binomial proportion confidence interval.

Comment: Based on a reasonable and easily supported prior distribution, my answer is *zero.*